# Check on the checkout page,if Logged In User Has Already Purchased a Product

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, hook

can someone help me,
i found this code and tried it and it works on the shop page

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_user_logged_in_product_already_bought', 30 );
  
function bbloomer_user_logged_in_product_already_bought() {
global $product;
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->get_id() ) ) echo '<div class="user-bought">&hearts; Hey ' . $current_user->first_name . ', you\'ve purchased this in the past. Buy again?</div>';
}
```

can someone over there change this code for notification only on the checkout page, before the customer continues the payment.
I want to show notifications only on the checkout page, not on any other page
Thank you very much

Comment: You need to be clear about whats the problem you are facing and what you have tried so far. Or what's the bug you are facing.  Stackoverflow is not a place for you to ask someone else to do the job for you.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much
I am sorry,
because I am a newbie, who do not understand how to ask questions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that your cart (review order part) on checkout page have many products and you want to show *Already Purchased* text somewhere near product name.

You can do this by overriding template. copy file from wp-plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php into your active theme (preferably child theme) here you can see how to create child theme (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). Now create woocommerce folder in your active theme if not exist, then create checkout folder if not exist and paste that file. Open that file and you can see the Cart loop around line no 31.

add code before that loop as follow:

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
}
```

Now, update loop code bit as follow:

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

    if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
        ?>
        <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
            <td class="product-name">
                <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times;&nbsp;%s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                <?php
                    // Here is your code -- Start
                    if( is_user_logged_in() && wc_customer_bought_product( $user->user_email, $user->ID, $_product->get_id() ) ) {
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_alredy_bought', '<div class="user-bought">' . sprintf( "Hi %s you already purchased in the past.", $user->first_name ) . '</div>' );
                    }
                    // Here is your code -- End
                ?>
            </td>
            <td class="product-total">
                <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
```

This should be working for you.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the help.
I just tried, and it worked out well on the checkout page.
but i need one more help from you for cart page

Comment: If this fixed for you please select it as accepted answer and yet tell me what help you want for cart page?

Comment: Hi,thank you very much
for the cart page,I want to make a notification like on the checkout page, Check whether the user has purchased the product,
Thank you

Comment: Do I have to set it like on the checkout page earlier

Comment: you mean cart page? You can do the same on cart page as well. The code will be similar just need to follow cart folder structure and need to override cart.php file into your active theme

Comment: I update the code whether it starts on line no 40. and ends with what line number. thank you so much for your help